# Data binding to ElementName in Page.BottomAppBar

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I am trying to bind an element inside the BottomAppBar to an element outside of it.

Here's a sample XAML to elucidate:

```
<Grid Background="{StaticResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <TextBox x:Name="text" MinWidth="200" MinHeight="40" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
</Grid>
<Page.BottomAppBar>
    <AppBar>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Button Content="{Binding Text, ElementName=text}" Click="Button_Click_1"></Button>
            <Button Content="{Binding Text, ElementName=text2}" Click="Button_Click_1"></Button>
            <TextBox x:Name="text2" MinWidth="200" MinHeight="40" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </AppBar>
</Page.BottomAppBar>
```

The first button never updates (the textbox it's bound to is outside of the BottomAppBar), however, the second button updates as you would expect. How do I make the page visible to BottomAppBar?

Comment: What if you use a common String property in your ViewModel and you bind it in both the Button and the Textbox ?

Comment: The actual scenario is more complex - I tried to simplify it for the question, though I could probably work with that (I will need to use two-way binding on one side to the "DefaultViewState" and go from there. It's just weird that this doesn't work 'out of the box'.

Comment: I am seeing this same behavior.  Seems like a bug to me.

Comment: I'm having the same issue, seems like a bug

Answer (score 1):

I don't have the audacity to say it's Bug, though that's what I believe it is, I played around this problem which coasts me like one week :

**First :** This is not just for the `BottomAppBar`, the `TopAppBar` suffers the same problem.

**Second :** The problem is that `ElementName` binding works only when your source Element is an Element that is inside one of the AppBars, that means :

- From `BottomAppBar`(target) to `TopAppBar`(source) : *Works*
- From `BottomAppBar`(target) to `BottomAppBar`(source) : *Works*
- From `TopAppBar`(target) to `BottomAppBar`(source) : *Works*
- From `TopAppBar`(target) to `TopAppBar`(source) : *Works*
- From `TopAppBar`(target) to Something outside the `two AppBars`(source) : *Doesn't Work*
- From `BottomAppBar`(target) to Something outside the `two AppBars`(source) : *Doesn't Work*

**Example :**

```
<Grid Background="{StaticResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <TextBox x:Name="text" MinWidth="200" MinHeight="40" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
</Grid>
<Page.TopAppBar>
    <AppBar>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Button Content="{Binding Text, ElementName=text}" Click="Button_Click_1"></Button>
            <Button Content="{Binding Text, ElementName=text2}" Click="Button_Click_1"></Button>
            <TextBox x:Name="text3" MinWidth="200" MinHeight="40" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
<TextBox x:Name="text3" MinWidth="200" MinHeight="40" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>

        </StackPanel>
    </AppBar>
</Page.TopAppBar>
<Page.BottomAppBar>
    <AppBar>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Button Content="{Binding Text, ElementName=text}" Click="Button_Click_1"></Button>
            <Button Content="{Binding Text, ElementName=text3}" Click="Button_Click_1"></Button>
            <TextBox x:Name="text2" MinWidth="200" MinHeight="40" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
<TextBox x:Name="text3" MinWidth="200" MinHeight="40" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>

        </StackPanel>
    </AppBar>
</Page.BottomAppBar>
```

The Content of the first button in both AppBars won't show anything, however the second button of both of the AppBars will show correctly.

I found out that the only thing that the AppBar sees from outside, is the `DataContext` of the root `Page` Element, hence think about using a backing property in the DataContext to handle all that, this works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work, because "text" TextBox is in different visual tree than button, so button doesn't know about "text". Such binding is impossible directly, but there exists solution.

Answer (score -1):

Can you try this

```
<Button Content="{Binding Path=text.Text}" Click="Button_Click_1"></Button>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It doesn't work - out of curiosity - why did you think it would? For this to work, the DataContext on the AppBar should somehow be the page itself or something. Was that your thought?

Comment: Gotcha. No - I didn't do that. Thanks again for the answer.